# change position of views

Tags: android, android-view

i use this code to change the position of my view

```
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myview.getLayoutParams();
  params.topMargin = topmargin;
  params.leftMargin = leftmargin;
  myview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and nothing change.but when i use this code

```
myview.setTop(topmargin);
myview.setLeft(leftmargin);
```

it will work.now i want to know what is wrong with my first code??

because in the internet so many people suggest first code to change the position of views.

**EDIT**

also this code doesn't work

```
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myview.getLayoutParams();
   params.setMargins(100,100,0,0);
   myview.setLayoutParams(params);
   myview.requestLayout();
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `myview.requestLayout();` after `myview.setLayoutParams(params);`

**UPDATE**

`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myview.getLayoutParams();
  params.setMargins(left,top, right,bottom);
  myview.setLayoutParams(params);
  myview.requestLayout();`

Comment: i post it.sorry for late

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `requestLayout()` after updating the layout params

```
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myview.getLayoutParams();
  params.topMargin = topmargin;
  params.leftMargin = leftmargin;
  myview.setLayoutParams(params);
  myview.requestLayout();
```

And this is a brief explanation from official documentation:

- [.setTop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTop(int)) ( same with `.setLeft()` )

> Sets the top position of this view relative to its parent. **This method
>   is meant to be called by the layout system and should not generally be
>   called otherwise**, because the property may be changed at any time by
>   the layout.

- [topMargin](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#topMargin) ( same with `leftMargin` )

> The top margin in pixels of the child. Margin values should be
>   positive. Call setLayoutParams(LayoutParams) after reassigning a new
>   value to this field.